# How to show that this exponential function has no JUMP discontinuities?

Tags: continuity, exponential-function

$$f(x)=a_1e^{b_1x}+a_2e^{b_2x}+\cdots+a_ne^{b_nx}$$

$$g(x)=c_1e^{d_1x}+c_2e^{d_2x}+\cdots+c_ne^{d_nx}$$

$a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$, $d_n$ are all REAL constants and $x$ is a REAL variable

How can I show that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ cannot have any JUMP discontinuities?

Comment: Do you see what are the points where $\frac {f}{g}$ may be discontinuous?

Comment: Also these functions $f$ and $g$ are not called exponential function.An exponential function is one which send $x \to e^x$.you may call $f$ and $g$ , $\mathbb R$ combination of exponential functions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about naming the function Arpit. I am aware that $f/g$ will have discontinuities when $g=0$, however, these will not be JUMP discontinuities

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{f(x)}}
{{g(x)}} = \frac{{a_{\,1} e^{\,b_{\,1} \,x} }}
{{c_{\,1} e^{\,d_{\,1} \,x}  + \; \cdots \; + c_{\,n} e^{\,d_{\,n} \,x} }} + \; \cdots \; + \frac{{a_{\,n} e^{\,b_{\,n} \,x} }}
{{c_{\,1} e^{\,d_{\,1} \,x}  + \; \cdots \; + c_{\,n} e^{\,d_{\,n} \,x} }} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{\left( {c_{\,1} /a_{\,1} } \right)e^{\,\left( {d_{\,1}  - b_{\,1} } \right)\,x}  + \; \cdots \; + \left( {c_{\,n} /a_{\,1} } \right)e^{\,\left( {d_{\,n}  - b_{\,1} } \right)\,x} }} + \; \cdots  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
So, since $g(x)$ in general is not null and does not have discontinuities, and $1/x$ is continuous for $x \ne 0$, then ...

Comment: An interesting piece of manipulation, thanks.

Comment: My hunch is that reasoning along the following lines may be mathematically sound: Each term in $f$ and $g$ is of the form $a_ne^{b_nx}$ and is continuous for all $x$ and a sum of such terms is therefore also continuous. This proves that $f$ and $g$ are individually continuous, hence $f/g$ must also be continuous except when $g=0$. As such $f/g$ is continuous and therefore can never have jump discontinuities. Is this reasoning correct ? All feedback greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Susan, correct, just add " ..except when $g(x)=0$, which does not happens since the exponential is never null and so is for its linear combinations".

Answer (score 1):

You're question is framed in the negative and it's often difficult to prove a negative.

Proving that $f/g$ is continuous is easier than proving it has NO JUMPS because if you can show it is continuous at all points then it is impossible for it to have JUMP, REMOVABLE, POINT or INFINITE discontinuities.

if $f$ and $g$ are individually continuous then their ration $f/g$ is continuous as long as $g$ is not zero. A sum of exp functions is clearly continuous since $e^{kx}$ is always continuous.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Quadratica. One final Q along the same lines. I cannot work out the continuity, points of 'defined-ness' and jumps of this function. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  ${arctanh(1+ix)^4-archtanh(1-ix)^4\over 2i}$  ($i$ is the root of -1)

Comment: You've chosen a great function to highlight the meaning of a jump discontinuity. I plotted the function on MATLAB and it throws up three points where the function has jumps $(-1,0,+1)$. At points other than these my plot shows it to be WELL-BEHAVED (ie continuous, differentiable and monotone)

Comment: But what if the graph of the function was not visible because the values were too large/small and you couldn't visibly identify the JDs, how then would you know they existed. There could be another function whose with JD but whose graph (for whatever reason) does not show up the JDs. This might happen if a function had a JD at $x=0.00001$ and another at $x=1000000$, there is NO WAY both these JDs can be seen on a graph.

Comment: Please read the logs. This question has been answered before. HERE. (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113253/finding-a-continuous-function-with-specified-properties/1936190#1936190)

Answer (score 0):

Erm....not quite true!!!. Try this!!

$a=arctan(1)$
   and   $b=arctan(2)$
define
$a(x)=-e^{2x}+8e^{x}-17+8e^{-x}-e^{-2x}$
 $b(x)=e^{2x}-8e^{x}+18-8e^{-2x}+e^{-2x}$
$c^2(x)=e^{4x}-16e^{3x}+100e^{2x}-304e^{x}+454-304e^{-x}+100e^{-2x}-16e^{-3x}+e^{-4x}$                               $d^2(x)=e^{4x}-16e^{3x}+98e^{2x}-288e^{x}+419-288e^{-x}+98e^{-2x}-16e^{-3x}+e^{-4x}$

then   $[a(x)/b(x)]*[c(x/d(x)]*cosec^{-1}(ax/b)$

has 4 jump discontinuities (finite types) at approx +/- 1.56679923697 and  +/- 0.962423650119. Where the lims differ but you'll need a darn high precision computer to verify it numerically. By jump I mean lims differ from below and above as per definition.